# Upper bound for the trace of product of two real symmetric matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

For symmetric matrices $A,B$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}_{2\times2}$, their eigenvalues are $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$ ($0\leq\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2$) and $\mu_1$,$\mu_2$ ($0\leq\mu_1 \leq \mu_2$), respectively.

Prove
$tr(AB)$$\leq$$\lambda_1$$\mu_1$+$\lambda_2$$\mu_2$.

When I tried to prove it, it may be solved with complex calculation.

I think there is much more simple or more intuitive way. I think rearrangement inequality would be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way of doing things: we can write
$$
A = \lambda_1 x_1x_1^T + \lambda_2 x_2x_2^T\\
B = \mu_1 y_1y_1^T + \mu_2 y_2y_2^T
$$
where the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are unit vectors.  We then calculate
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = 
\lambda_1 \mu_1 (x_1^Ty_1)^2 + 
\lambda_1 \mu_2 (x_1^Ty_2)^2 + 
\lambda_2 \mu_1 (x_2^Ty_1)^2 + 
\lambda_2 \mu_2 (x_2^Ty_2)^2
$$
Now, define $t = (x_1^Ty_1)^2$.  We can rewrite the above as
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = 
t \lambda_1 \mu_1  + 
(1-t)\lambda_1 \mu_2  + 
(1-t)\lambda_2 \mu_1 + 
t\lambda_2 \mu_2 =\\
t [\lambda_1 \mu_1 + \lambda_2 \mu_2] +
(1-t)[\lambda_1\mu_2 + \lambda_2\mu_1]
$$
Where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.  It suffices to maximize this quantity.

Also, note that
$$
[\lambda_1 \mu_1 + \lambda_2 \mu_2] - 
[\lambda_1\mu_2 + \lambda_2\mu_1] = 
(\lambda_2 - \lambda_1)(\mu_2 - \mu_1) \geq 0
$$

Comment: $x_i$ and $y_i$ are eigenvector of A and B, right? Then, I am curious about any symmetric matrix is equal to summation of $\lambda_i$$x_i$$x_i^T$. I first encountered this property, today. Is this famous property?

Comment: Yes, $x_i$ and $y_i$ are eigenvectors.  This is one way of writing the spectral theorem.